# android ignore special character input

Tags: android, character

Could any Android expert please help with an input filter to ignore the character `-`?

I set up a class for doing this, but all characters are ignored.....

```
public class InputFilterReservedCharacters implements InputFilter {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try {
        if (end > start) {
            for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {
                if (source.charAt(index) == "-".toCharArray()[0]) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Thanks to StoneBird for your helpful comment, I'd like user to be enter anything except the '-'. I got it working this way:

```
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    String returnValue = "";

    try {
        if (end > start) {
            for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {
                if (source.charAt(index) != '-'){
                    returnValue = Character.toString(source.charAt(index));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: By ignore do you mean, you want to remove '-' from a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `if (source.charAt(index) == "-".toCharArray()[0]) {return "";}` means if the function finds `-` then the function will return `""` as the result, and **thereby ending the execution of this function.** That's why you get empty result every time, because the filter is working and doing what you want it to return.
Try creating an empty string in your function, concatenate all "useful" chars to that string, and return that.

```
public class InputFilterReservedCharacters implements InputFilter {

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    private CharSequence result = ""; //change here
    try {
    if (end > start) {
        for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {
            if (source.charAt(index) != "-".toCharArray()[0]) { //change here
                result+=source.charAt(index);
            }
        }
    }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    return result; //and here
}
}
```

Also I believe using `'-'` rather than double quote gives you a char, so you don't need to convert it to char array.